# Problems with multiple setIntervals running simultaneously

Tags: javascript, dhtml, menubar, setinterval

My first post here. I want to make a horizontal menu with submenu's sliding down on mouseover. I know I could use jQuery but this is to practice my javascript skills.

I use the following code:

```
var up = new Array()
var down = new Array()
var submenustart

function titleover(headmenu, inter)
{
 submenu = headmenu.lastChild

 up[inter] = window.clearInterval(up[inter])
 down[inter] = window.setInterval("slidedown(submenu)",1)
}

function slidedown(submenu)
{
 if(submenu.offsetTop < submenustart)
 {
  submenu.style.top = submenu.offsetTop + 1 + "px"
 }
}

function titleout(headmenu, inter)
{
 submenu = headmenu.lastChild

 down[inter] = window.clearInterval(down[inter])
 up[inter] = window.setInterval("slideup(submenu)", 1)

}

function slideup(submenu)
{
 if(submenu.offsetTop > submenustart - submenu.clientHeight + 1)
 {
  submenu.style.top = submenu.offsetTop - 1 + "px"
 }
}
```

The variable submenustart gets appointed a value in another function which is not relevant for my question.
HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="hoofding" id="hoofding">
 <tr>
  <td onmouseover="titleover(this, 0)" onmouseout="titleout(this, 0)"><a href="#" class="hoofdinglink" id="hoofd1">AAAA</a>

  <table class="menu">
   <tr><td><a href="...">1111</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="...">2222</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="...">3333</a></td></tr>
  </table></td>

  <td onmouseover="titleover(this, 1)" onmouseout="titleout(this, 1)"><a href="#" class="hoofdinglink">BBBB</a>

  <table class="menu">
   <tr><td><a href="...">1111</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="...">2222</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="...">3333</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="...">4444</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="...">5555</a></td></tr>
  </table></td>
        ...
 </tr>
</table>
```

What happens is the following:
If I go over and out (for ex) menu A it works fine.
If i go now over menu B the interval applied to A is now applied to B. There are now 2 interval functions applied to B. The one originally for A and a new one triggered by the mouseover on B.
If I would go to A all the intervals are now applied to A.

I have been searching for hours but and I am completely stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't forget to call `clearInterval` when you're done animating.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, but I was aware of this. I did add this clearInterval later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first suggestion is to

1. Practice using semicolons properly and not relying on semicolon insertion
2. Don't pass functions as strings (which requires an implicit `eval`)
3. [use JavaScript to attach events in a non-obtrusive manner](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html)

.

```
var up   = [],
    down = [],
    submenustart;

function titleover(headmenu, inter) {
    up[inter]   = window.clearInterval(up[inter]);
    down[inter] = window.setInterval(function() { slidedown(headmenu.lastChild); }, 1);
}

function slidedown(submenu) {
    if ( submenu.offsetTop < submenustart  ) {
        submenu.style.top = submenu.offsetTop + 1 + "px";
    }
}

function titleout(headmenu, inter) {
    down[inter] = window.clearInterval(down[inter]);
    up[inter]   = window.setInterval(function() { slideup(headmenu.lastChild); }, 1);
}

function slideup(submenu) {
    if ( submenu.offsetTop > submenustart - submenu.clientHeight + 1 ) {
        submenu.style.top = submenu.offsetTop - 1 + "px";
    }
}
```

My second suggestion is to not use tables for menus, as they aren't tabular data.  Instead, use an unsorted list.

```
<ul class="hoofding" id="hoofding">
    <li onmouseover="titleover(this, 0)" onmouseout="titleout(this, 0)">
        <a href="#" class="hoofdinglink" id="hoofd1">AAAA</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="...">1111</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">2222</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">3333</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li onmouseover="titleover(this, 1)" onmouseout="titleout(this, 1)">
        <a href="#" class="hoofdinglink">BBBB</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="...">1111</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">2222</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">3333</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not passing the function as a string indeed solved the problem. Thanks.
I will also take notice of your other suggestions.

It seems I don't have enough reputation to vote up your anser. Otherwise you had my vote.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, (and according to the Gecko DOM reference) window.clearInterval() does not return anything, which maybe the reason which messes things up.

Comment: True, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. The ID is being cleared and then the variable is set to undefined.